# How do I use PHP to manipulate the way a taxonomy term is displayed within a view?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, media

My objective: I want to display a specific image when a node has a taxonomy term. All of my nodes are being displayed using the views module.

What I have done so far: I have a content type, it has a term reference field linked to the taxonomy vocabulary I desire. Within views I have linked my field with the view so it displays the taxonomy term text in the desired view.

What I need: I am thinking my next step should be creating a template file that connects with my view and write some php that states "If **this** taxonomy term is selected, then use **this** CSS but if **this** taxonomy term is selected use **this** CSS"

The CSS would have a background image of my choice which would connect with the term chosen.

I am doing this because I want to add product "for sale", "Free", "New" stickers to my products and I am trying to make it as automated as possible.

If anyone has a better idea on how to do this or can offer some help I would really appreciate it.

I am using Drupal 7.1 and  Drupal Commerce

Comment: That could easily become many if statements. Two other solutions would be to either add an image field to the taxonomy, or add a class name based on the term name (with [drupal_clean_css_identifier()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_clean_css_identifier/7). I can write a proper answer tomorrow (00:16 CET here), but first, which version of Drupal are you using?